# Is it possible to use Bazaar with SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, bazaar, sonarqube-5.0

I've just installed the latest SonarQube 5.0.1 locally to try it out.  The project I'm working with at the moment is hosted in Bazaar (bzr) source control.  I looked at the SonarQube list of SCM plugins here:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library

Bazaar is not listed.  Are there any workarounds or independent projects that I could use to get the scm history information from Bazaar into SonarQube?  At this point I am just trying to get a sense of the value of the information to our project, rather than worry about a scalable production-ready solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently (2015-04-09) no SCM plugin for Bazaar. If you wish to contribute one, feel free to take inspiration from e.g the [SonarQube SCM integration plugin for Git](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-git).